# Why I can not connect to websocket via chrome although firefox can?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, websocket, tornado

I'm sorry because you may seem it's kind of a noob question but believe me I've looked for it on the net also in stackoverflow, however people had seen that kind of problem with firefox which is exact opposite of what I have. I want to ask 2 questions related to this issue with your permission,

1. why there is not a browser standard while connecting to websockets? I mean why still are there differences between browsers?
2. why I'm getting disconnect while trying with chrome although I can connect with firefox, do I need to set something on the chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact issue you're having, but I ran into issues with Websockets as well with some of the telco providers here, it just will not work.

I used SockJS (https://github.com/sockjs) which and managed to get it working. It first uses websockets but falls back to http polling, etc. when websockets fail. Hope this helps!